# lodash groupBy with array length

Tags: lodash

I have an original Array that looks like this:

```
const original = [
    {
        type: 'foo'
    },
    {
        type: 'foo'
    },
    {
        type: 'bar'
    }
]
```

I then run it through lodash groupBy with the iteratee `(val) => val.type` to get:

```
{
  bar: [{
  type: "bar"
}],
  foo: [{
  type: "foo"
}, {
  type: "foo"
}]
}
```

Is there a lodash way to convert/reduce the properties of each key into their Array.length?

```
{
  bar: 1,
  foo: 2
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `_.countBy()` to get that result directly:

```js
const original = [{"type":"foo"},{"type":"foo"},{"type":"bar"}]

const result = _.countBy(original, 'type')

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

To get the same result after grouping the array, use `_.mapValues()`, and get the length of each sub-array using `_.size()`:

```js
const original = [{"type":"foo"},{"type":"foo"},{"type":"bar"}]

const result = _.mapValues(
  _.groupBy(original, 'type'),
  _.size,
)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```